# Angular2 Type 'Promise<ClientInformations>' is not assignable to type 'ClientInformations>

Tags: javascript, angular

EDIT: Complete my question with a missing error message.

I'm trying to perform a HTTP reqeust on my web server via Angular2.

Here is my method :

```
getClientInformations(id): Promise<ClientInformations> {
    return this.http.post(this.clientInfoUrl, 
                          JSON.stringify({ data: id }), 
                        { headers: this.headers })
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json() as ClientInformations)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I got 2 error :

> Property 'ClientId' is missing in type 'Promise< ClientInformations >'.
>
> Type 'Promise < ClientInformations >' is not assignable to type
>   'ClientInformations'

Here is client.informations.ts :

```
export class ClientInformations {
    ClientId: string;
    ClientName: string;
    NbUser: number;
}
```

Comment: Did u solved it? @Morgan

Comment: Yes, it was dumb, I called getClientInformations() on another type than 'ClientInformations'. @Despertaweb